# Virtual memory exception when dealing with large binary files

Tags: vb.net, playframework-2.0, out-of-memory, virtual

I get a virtual memory exception error when transforming a (2~3 megabytes) binary file to a different format.
This error only happens on low performance PCs with 100 Mbytes of virtual memory.
[Performance report in realtime (.net Memory profiler)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6mpM.png)

here is the code where this memory usage increase occurs:

```
Using reader As BinaryReader = New BinaryReader(New FileStream(strSrcFileName, FileMode.Open))
    Dim BuffOffset As Integer 'offset of reading the DAT file every time
    Dim RecSize As Integer 'no of records to process each time
    While intRecordsCount > 0 'reader.BaseStream.Position <> reader.BaseStream.Length
        If intRecordsCount > RecordsChunck Then
            RecSize = RecordsChunck
            intRecordsCount -= RecordsChunck
        Else
            RecSize = intRecordsCount
            intRecordsCount = 0
        End If
        Dim tempBuffer(RecSize * intRecordLength - 1) As Byte
        Dim outputbuffer(RecSize * (intRecordLength - 8) - 1) As Byte

        reader.BaseStream.Seek(BuffOffset, SeekOrigin.Begin)
        reader.Read(tempBuffer, 0, tempBuffer.Length)
        BuffOffset += tempBuffer.Length 'prepare the offset for the next reading

                'conversion is done here

        'append the converted buffer into the target binary file
        Using writer As BinaryWriter = New BinaryWriter(File.Open(strTargetFileName, FileMode.Append))
            writer.Write(outputbuffer)
        End Using
    End While 
End Using
```

The increase is happening as expected when appending the target file (writer stream)

My question is what can I to do to avoid that (much) memory usage when both source and target files were loaded, and what is the best practice in such cases?

Comment: How much RAM do you have? Change the swap file size and increase it to the same as however much RAM you have.

Comment: thank you for your response, the physical RAM is 128Mbs only. but is there any way to optimize the above code?

Comment: You could open both files at the same time and read and write smaller chunks I guess.